# Datastax Enterprise Graph GroupCount Order

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have multiple documents.
I have multiple users.
Users read documents.

I want to get documents that were read by user Stefan.

```
g.V().
has('user','name','Stefan').
out('read').
hasLabel('document')
```

What other users has read the same document? And what other documents are those users reading which the user Stefan doesn't have:

```
g.V().
has('user','name','Stefan').
out('read').
hasLabel('document').
in('read').
has('user','name',neq('Stefan')).
out('read').
match(
    __.as('d').hasLabel('document'),
    __.not(__.as('d').hasLabel('document').in('read').has('user','name','Stefan'))
).
select('d').valueMap('docId','title')
```

Now I want to sort this by the number of user that read the document with groupCount.

```
g.V().
has('user','name','Stefan').
out('read').
hasLabel('document').
in('read').
has('user','name',neq('Stefan')).
out('read').
match(
    __.as('d').hasLabel('document'),
    __.not(__.as('d').hasLabel('document').in('read').has('user','name','Stefan'))
).
select('d').valueMap('docId','title').
groupCount().by().
order(local).by(values,decr)
```

This will work, but the result is not what I want:

```
{
  "{docId=[33975], title=[Doc1 - 5 - 1]}": 3,
  "{docId=[33379], title=[Doc2 - 5]}": 2,
  "{docId=[32474], title=[Doc3 - 5]}": 2,
  "{docId=[31150], title=[Doc4 2-2013]}": 1,
  "{docId=[107944], title=[Doc5]}": 1
}
```

The key is folded. I want to have 3 columns in my result:

1. DocId
2. Title
3. GroupCount value.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try `unfold`

Comment: Yes, i tried unfold. `select('d').valueMap('docId','title').unfold().` But that gave me multiple rows as result. `{
  "docId=[33975]": 3,
  "title=[Quest 2013 - 5 - 1]": 3}`